# Creating a pandas data frame of specific Shape from a list of items

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

I have a pandas dataframe f a specific size say:

```
   ID  FACTOR    LEVEL
  160  SPM       P                       
  159  SPM2      S                         
  851  ABS       K                        
  415  ABS       P                       
  202  ABS       P 
  205  ABS2      Q
  207  AQE       T
```

What I want to do is that I have a list say of two items: 
 X = ['GAB', 'YER']

So what I want to do is that I want to distribute this items in the list as a new column say NewCol with a specific frequency as the same size of the rows in the dataframe. So in this case say I have 7 rows and 2 items and 7/2 integer quotient is 3, so I want to put the first item in 3 rows and the next one in the remaining 4 rows. So the output should like :

```
         ID  FACTOR    LEVEL  NewCol
        160  SPM       P        GAB               
        159  SPM2      S        GAB                 
        851  ABS       K        GAB               
        415  ABS       P        YER               
        202  ABS       P        YER
        205  ABS2      Q        YER
        207  AQE       T        YER
```

So what I was able to do so far is to create a a series of two elements using

```
 df_s = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

which is giving me

```
     0
    GAB
    YER
```

However, I am not able to create a series out of this of the shape of the dataframe with the values in X and neither I am able to find a way to distribute it. I am still working on it, but some help/hints from the experts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.repeat` and assign the result to a new column:

```
arr = np.repeat(X, len(df) // len(X))
df['NewCol'] = pd.Series(arr, index=df.index[:len(arr)])
df

    ID FACTOR LEVEL NewCol
0  160    SPM     P    GAB
1  159   SPM2     S    GAB
2  851    ABS     K    GAB
3  415    ABS     P    YER
4  202    ABS     P    YER
5  205   ABS2     Q    YER
6  207    AQE     T    NaN
```

If you want to fill the last NaN, use,

```
df['NewCol'] = df['NewCol'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 2):

Some different idea using `clip`

```
import numpy as np 
n=len(X)
m=len(df)//n 
s=pd.Series(np.arange(len(df))//m).clip_upper(n-1)
df['New']=s.map(dict(zip(s.unique(),X)))
df
Out[278]: 
    ID FACTOR LEVEL  New
0  160    SPM     P  GAB
1  159   SPM2     S  GAB
2  851    ABS     K  GAB
3  415    ABS     P  YER
4  202    ABS     P  YER
5  205   ABS2     Q  YER
6  207    AQE     T  YER
```

Comment: Yes, this is a new method, I never used, clip earlier. Learned a new thing! Thanks